# Append text to URL src via jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, attr

I'm scraping some content and there's this image which has this:

```
<div id="targetImage"><img src="alfresco/nap/webAssets/webPage/homepage/desktop/common/intl/global/images/primary-v=1.13.jpg" alt="" title="" width="550" height="682"></div>
```

I need to append

```
"http://www.targetdomain.com/"
```

before

```
"alfresco"
```

What is the best method to achieve this via jquery? Do I need regex for this?

Thanks

Comment: Is that HTML on your page or is it in a string obtained by your scraper? How are you scraping in the first place?

Comment: remember that you can always use [`<BASE>`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/base)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var img= $("#targetImage img:first");
img.attr("src", "http://www.targetdomain.com/"+img.attr("src"));
```

Here is a fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/9ajgj/1/

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
var img = $("#targetImage").children("img")[0];
img.attr("src", "http://www.targetdomain.com/"+img.attr("src"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var root = 'http://www.targetdomain.com/';
$('.someContent').find('img').each(function(index, image) {
    image.src.indexOf('http') !== 0 && (image.src = root + image.src);
});
```